# Visual studio unable to resolve overloaded unambiguous function in class and namespace

Tags: c++

See code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace stringhelper
{
    std::string to_string(int n) { return "0"; } // ignore wrong implementation. simplified for example purpose
}

using stringhelper::to_string;

class TestClass
{
public:
    std::string to_string() const { return "TestClass:" + to_string(m_value); }

private:
    int m_value;
};

int main()
{
    TestClass tc;
    std::cout << tc.to_string();
}
```

If TestClass does not implement function `to_string()`, within `TestClass`, it is able to resolve `to_string(m_value)` to `stringhelper::to_string(int)`. However, the moment TestClass implements function to_string(), the compiler is unable to resolve `to_string(int)` to `stringhelper::to_string`.
Rather, it insists/resolves the function to `TestClass::to_string` and gave an error that the function `TestClass::to_string` does not take in 1 arguments.

Why is this so?

> **Environment:**
>
> Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition 9.0.21022.8 RTM
>
> Configuration: Win32
>
> Windows 8

Comment: One reason why using `using` is usually frowned upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is not limited to Visual Studio 2008. If tested in modern Clang implementations you will see the same behaviour. As you may know, functions in derived classes which don't override functions in base classes but which have the same name will hide other functions of the same name in the base class.

The "problem" here is that you, by using the `using` statement introduces a function named `to_string` into a scope that is essentially a victim of the exact same thing as what happens in the above example, when looking at it from inside your class.

If the standard had you call member functions with `this->foo()` this would probably not have been an issue. But since function calls within a class are presumed to be part of the class and only if not found looked for in other scopes this becomes an issue.

Since you have an implementation in your class, that has priority and will be used. Since you want a version that takes an `int` as an argument, an overloaded version of your member function will be looked for and since it does not exist you get the error you see.

This is part of why `using namespace` can often introduce errors that might be unintuitive to understand. If you want to make sure you use the `stringhelper::to_string` implementation while you are in a class with a function that has the same name you have to be explicit.

This would work fine for instance, even if you keep your `using` statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace stringhelper
{
    std::string to_string(int n) { return "0"; } // ignore wrong implementation. simplified for example purpose
}

using stringhelper::to_string;

class TestClass
{
public:
    std::string to_string() const { return "TestClass:" + stringhelper::to_string(m_value); }

private:
    int m_value;
};

int main()
{
    TestClass tc;
    std::cout << tc.to_string();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I always thought that function hiding is only for hiding the functions with the same signature. Now then I know that once the compiler finds a function with the same name, it will stop searching in 'higher' scope. The reason why I am not inclined to prefix with stringhelper is because there are tons of code using it. Besides, to_string is part of c++ standard which unfortunately, visual studio 2008 does not support yet and I am unable to upgrade to a newer version of visual studio.